# How to get scalar result from prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, variables, prepared-statement, mysql-error-1064

Is it possible to set the result from a prepared statement into a variable?  I am trying to create the following stored procedure but it is failing:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 31: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'stmt USING @m, @c, @a;

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS deleteAction;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteAction(
    IN modul CHAR(64),
    IN controller CHAR(64),
    IN actn CHAR(64))

MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN

    PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT id 
                         FROM actions 
                        WHERE `module` = ? 
                          AND `controller` = ? 
                          AND `action` = ?';

    SET @m = modul;
    SET @c = controller;
    SET @a = actn;

    SET @i = EXECUTE stmt USING @m, @c, @a;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    DELETE FROM acl WHERE action_id = @i;
    DELETE FROM actions WHERE id = @i; 

END 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may seem strange, but you can assign the variable directly in the prepared statement string:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT @i := id FROM ...';

-- ...

EXECUTE stmt USING @m, @c, @a;

-- @i will hold the id returned from your query.
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE actions (id int, a int);

INSERT INTO actions VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO actions VALUES (2, 200);
INSERT INTO actions VALUES (3, 300);
INSERT INTO actions VALUES (4, 400);
INSERT INTO actions VALUES (5, 500);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(
    IN p int
)

MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN

    PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT @i := id FROM actions WHERE `a` = ?';

    SET @a = p;

    EXECUTE stmt USING @a;

    SELECT @i AS result;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Result:

```
CALL myProc(400);

+---------+
| result  |
+---------+
|       4 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I know this answer is very old but can anyone tell me: when I use this code and I use CALL myProc(600), it doesn't return an empty query result but instead returns whatever was the last 'valid' call.  Why is that and how can I change that?  It should return 'result' as empty when I pass it a value not in in the table.

Comment: 12 years later...

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT ''a'' into @i' ;

EXECUTE stmt;

if(@i='a') then
............
end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

not even sure why you're using dynamic sql in your example - this seems a lot simpler

```
drop procedure if exists deleteAction;

delimiter #

create procedure deleteAction
(
 in p_modul char(64),
 in p_controller char(64),
 in p_actn char(64)
)
begin

declare v_id int unsigned default 0;

    select id into v_id from actions where 
          module = p_modul and controller = p_controller and action = p_actn;

    delete from acl where action_id = v_id;
    delete from actions where id = v_id; 

    select v_id as result;

end #

delimiter ;

call deleteAction('mod','ctrl','actn');
```