# MySql, combining variables to make the name of a variable?

Tags: mysql, variables, join, reference, concatenation

I'm currently writing a function in MySql that requires I be able to do something of the following sort:

```
 SET argNumber = 2;
 SELECT x.x_id 
   FROM x, piv
  WHERE x.x_id = concat('piv.x', argNumber)
  LIMIT 1;
```

As you can see above, i am attempting to concat 'piv.x' and the variable value of argNumber to create piv.x2, which is a column in the table piv.  the problem I am having is that after i use the concat function, the procedure treats the resulting string as data instead of as a reference.  How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It should rather be (assuming `piv.x` is a `varchar` column else you need to cast it to proper type first)

```
concat(piv.x, '2')
```

your query should look like

```
 SELECT x.x_id 
 FROM x JOIN piv
  ON x.x_id = concat( CAST(piv.x AS VARCHAR), argNumber)
  LIMIT 1;
```

Per your comment looks like you need a dynamic query. Then do like below

```
SET @sql =CONCAT("SELECT x.x_id FROM x JOIN piv ON x.x_id = piv.x", argNumber, " LIMIT 1");
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I think that @testingturing is trying to use concat to compose a Field name

Comment: It's still not running for me.  I am currently testing outside of my procedure so i have declared argnumber using SELECT @argNumber : = 2, so maybe that is why?

Comment: @TestingTuring, looks like you need a dynamic query. See edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: @genespos, Yes and it's his latest edit invalidated my answer. see edit now.

Comment: I am a bit confused about how the prepare statement works.  It looks like it  takes what is in front of it, concats it, and treats it as if it were hand typed.     So then i could also use Prepare stmt FROM 'my select statement', variable a, variable b, etc, 'more of the select statement', and i should get the same result as what you have posted, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create dynamic SQL with [`PREPARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
SET argNumber = 2;
PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('
    SELECT x.x_id 
    FROM x, piv
    WHERE x.x_id = piv.x', argNumber, '
    LIMIT 1');
EXECUTE stmt;
```

To get the result of the `SELECT` into a variable, you can assign to a variable in the statement, as explained here:

[How to get scalar result from prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992454/how-to-get-scalar-result-from-prepared-statement)

```
PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('
    SELECT @id := x.x_id 
    FROM x, piv
    WHERE x.x_id = piv.x', argNumber, '
    LIMIT 1');
```

After you execute the statement, the variable `@id` contains the selected ID.

Comment: In my situation, i will be calling this statement from inside a procedure and i will be setting a variable to the result of that select statement.  Is there anything else i should know about using the prepare statement?

Comment: it's not running right for me.  Is there a reason for the parenthesis after concat?

Comment: `CONCAT` is a function, the parentheses contain the arguments that should be concatenated.

Comment: @TestingTuring See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992454/how-to-get-scalar-result-from-prepared-statement for how to get the result of the statement.